# encrypting a string using bouncycastle c#

Tags: c#, certificate, bouncycastle

Currently learning about reading in the certificate from the windows store.
 then using the private and public keys to encrypt a string then decrypt it.

I have a certificate in my store which has the public and private key assigned to it.

I'm reading in the public key fine using

```
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        foreach (X509Certificate2 certificate in store.Certificates)
        {
            //TODO's
            byte[] encodedPublicKey = certificate.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData;
            File.WriteAllLines(filePath, new[] {
            "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----",
            Convert.ToBase64String(encodedPublicKey, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks),
                "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
            });

            publicKey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);

            encryptedWithPublic = encryption.EncryptWithPublic(input, publicKey);
        }
        store.Close();
```

i then call this method to encrypt

```
var bytesToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);

        var encryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

        using (var txtreader = new StringReader(publicKey))
        {
            var keyParameter = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(txtreader).ReadObject();

            encryptEngine.Init(true, keyParameter);
        }

        var encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytesToEncrypt, 0, bytesToEncrypt.Length));
        return encrypted;
```

Note - when i create my own public key the above method works, but when i use a public key from the keystore it is falling with

Additional information: Unknown object in GetInstance: 
   Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerInteger

clearly i'm doing something wrong when i'm reading in from the store but i've not managed to find any help on here with this issue

Comment: Did not seem to be C. I understand it is C#. Changed tag accordingly.